# Find the limit of this integral:

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Consider the following:

$$\int_x^{3x}\frac{1}{\arctan t}dt$$
find the limit for $x\rightarrow+\infty$. My reasoning goes as: first integrate by parts
$$\int_x^{3x}\frac{1}{\arctan t}dt=\frac{t}{\arctan t}\Bigg|_x^{3x}+\int_x^{3x}\frac{t}{t^2+1}\frac{1}{(\arctan t)^2}dt$$

as all the functions involved are positive we can say the inequality holds true:
$$\int_x^{3x}\frac{1}{\arctan t}dt>\frac{t}{\arctan t}\Bigg|_x^{3x}=x\Big(\frac{3}{\arctan 3x}-\frac{1}{\arctan x}\Big)\underset{x\rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow+\infty}$$
meaning the integral diverges. Is there any mistake? Since the interval of integration is increasing and both the extremes diverge asymptotically the same way, it doesn't sound right to me for this integral to actually diverge.

Comment: Hint: $\frac 1{\arctan t}>\frac 2\pi$ so it is trivially divergent.

Comment: Heuristically speaking, I think it makes plenty of sense for this to diverge.  arctan gets so close to pi/2 in the limit that it becomes essentially constant, and replacing the integrand with pi/2 will certainly result in something that diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t>1$, then $\arctan(t) \in (\pi/4,\pi/2)$ and hence
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}<\frac{1}{\arctan(t)}<\frac{4}{\pi}
$$
and
$$
\frac{2\cdot 2x}{\pi}<\int_x^{3x}\frac{dt}{\arctan(t)}<\frac{4\cdot 2x}{\pi}
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_x^{3x}\frac{dt}{\arctan(t)}=\infty.
$$